# Difference between http:// and http:\\

Tags: http, url

What is difference between writing a URL (say google.com)
  http://www.google.com 
      and
  http:\\www.google.com

Comment: it is basic thing to access web URL

Comment: @adi why You ask question like this?

Comment: This seems like a very reasonable question.

Comment: Maybe for someone with a Windows background? ;)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash

Comment: @lpa: well frankly even i was shocked when it  was asked to me in an interview

Comment: I see , I thought ur kidding, Shashank Kadne explained correct answer very well

Answer (score 6):

The syntax for url's is this..

```
scheme://domain:port/path?query_string
```

Comment: Almost, it's actually `scheme://domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id` ...

Answer (score 5):

One works and the other doesn't.

Comment: There was no **"why"** in the OP question. :)

Answer (score 2):

`http:\\www.google.com` is not valid URL address.

Comment: but it works in most of browsers like Google chrome and IE(doesn't work in Mozilla)

Comment: this because these browsers include auto-url-fix feature which can simply detect any invalid URL pattern and fix it...

Answer (score 2):

Backslash is [wrong](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/revsol.html). Do not use `\` for URLs.

Comment: its \\ and not just backlash(\)..sorry for typing mistake

Answer (score 2):

You can ask why `http:##google.com` or `http:%%google.com` is not working? Because it's built so. It's a kind of a rule: "for `abc` protocol write `abc://`"

Comment: @ShashankKadne answered perfectly.